# Why doesn't my while loop in an async method stop?

Tags: c#, while-loop

I've got the following code in an `async` method in my app

```
b_saving = true;

while (b_saving == true)
{
     try
     {
          if (1 == 1)
                b_saving = false;

          // anything down here should not execute?               
          i_should_not_run();

     }
     catch{
     }
     finally{
     }
}
```

My expectation with this code is that it will stop as soon as b_saving is set to false. Yet when I run it, this is not the case. Breakpoints show the method continues on even when b_saving is false.

Do while loops not work this way in C#?

Comment: put break; after b_saving = false;

Comment: In short: a while condition is only checked at the start of the loop, so the **entire** loop is executed, then b_saving is checked again.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the loop will continue even after you set the `b_saving` to false, unless you put a `break` command in there, the while loop will continue executing until the end of its block and only then re-evaluate the condition and in this case most likely avoid another iteration of the loop, unless you set back `b_saving` to true inside your `i_should_not_run` method.

PS you can write a simpler condition in the while, no need to put the ==...

```
  while (b_saving)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
b_saving = true;

while (b_saving == true)
{
     try
     {
          bool stop = true;

          if (stop == true)
          {
                b_saving = false;
                break;
          }

          // anything down here should not execute?               
          i_should_not_run();

     }
     catch{
     }
     finally{
     }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Well it will carry on running for one run through the code, until the `While` check is carried out.

If you want to break out of the loop early then you want a `break;` statement.

Comment: I am trying to abort the method when certain conditions are detected. I'll try `break`, thanks.

Comment: @roryok If you use `break` it is likely that you don't need the `b_saving` variable, and you can remove it and change the `while` to `while (true)`.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `break` to stop execution like following

```
b_saving = true;

while (b_saving == true)
{
     try
     {
          if (1 == 1){
                b_saving = false;
                break; // Will exit the loop
             }

          // anything down here should not execute?               
          i_should_not_run();

     }
     catch{
     }
     finally{
     }
}
```

[Read](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/adbctzc4.aspx) :

> The break statement terminates the closest enclosing loop or switch statement in which it appears. Control is passed to the statement that follows the terminated statement, if any.

Answer (score 0):

In order for the while loop to stop and not continue to execute the method your if statement should be like this:

```
if(1 == 1)
{
    b_saving = false;
    break;
}
```

The break keyword will exit the loop.

Comment: `b_saving = false;` is redundant, just `break` is enough

Comment: what if he wants to use the b_saving after the loop?

Answer (score 0):

This has nothing to do with the async or the try/catch.

Setting `b_saving` to false is only part of the story - it has nil effect until you actually *test its value and take an action based on that* (in this case exit the `while` loop).

This is the way while loops always run.

You might also get interesting results from a compiler (depending on the language) - some of that code may get eliminated as it is effectively useless.

Answer (score 0):

This loop should execute once as the first time `b_saving == true`. within the loop you set `b_saving` to false so it won't execute a second time.

To prevent `i_should_not_run` from being called add a `break` statement.

Answer (score 0):

Few points:

1. The code above would complete the entire loop after setting the
   m_saving flag to false, i you want it to stop right away you should
   state it using the break keyword.
2. Judging by the name of the "m_saving" member you use, it's a local variable, therefore in a multithreaded scenario you should use read and write to it using atomic operation mechanisms.
3. Should the catch block be empty?
4. Just a template to consider

   for{;;} 
     {
         try
         {
          if(hasToStop)
          { 
              break;
          }
         }
         catch { hasToStop = true;}
     }