# Neatest way to stop execution in a method

Tags: c#, break

Related to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28497132/why-doesnt-my-while-loop-stop/28497181#28497181)

Suppose I have a long method which I want to abort on certain conditions. What's the best way to do this? Here are two ways I can think of.

```
try
{
    // if i is 0, we don't want to continue
    int i = testi();
    if(i == 0)
        throw new StopException("stop")

    // the rest of our code
}
catch(StopException stop)
{
    // handle our stop exception
}
catch{
    // everything else
}
```

Here's another

```
bool go = true
while(go)
{
    // if i is 0, we don't want to continue
    int i = testi();
    if(i == 0)
    {
        go = false;
        break;
    }
    // the rest of our code
}
```

Both of these seem clunky. Throwing an exception seems like overkill, and I don't actually want to loop anything so `while` is being misused. It seems to me there should be (and probably is) a more elegant way of doing this in C#?

## RETURN!

Doy. I have actually used this lots of times, for some reason it just popped out of my head today. Thanks for indulging me in my stupidity

Comment: Why not just use `return`?

Comment: If using `return` isn't appropriate, perhaps your method needs to be refactored.

Comment: 1- Don't use try-catch for program flow control. It is bad practice. 2- You don't need to set go=false if you're breaking out of the loop anyway.

Comment: @MartinSmith bad coding. breaking out of the while would stop execution of the rest of the code.

Comment: Maybe you could use some online tutorials? I always recommend this guy: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=m4gHh2By8rQ&index=4&list=PLF932FF551E0ADD16

Comment: @roryok Continue; also continues while loop and rest of the code will not work I think

Comment: Thanks guys. feeling particularly stupid today

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The standard way to interrupt a C# method is by simply using the `return` statement.

if method is void simply `return`, if not then `return null` or `return 0` depends on the case.

definitely no need to throw and exception just instead of a return.

Answer (score 0):

Just exit the method using the `return` statement.

```
void longMethod()
{
    int i = testi();
    if(i == 0)
        return;

    // Continue with method
}
```